# How to make bootstrap carousel buttons always adjacent to each other

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make these bootstrap buttons immediately adjacent to each other, so they're always touching (no matter the screen size.) But I just can't seem to manage it. Any ideas?

```
  <div class="buttons">
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#testimonials" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#testimonials" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>

a {
  background-color: white;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 2;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 30px 0px hsl(240, 18%, 79%);
}

.carousel-control-next {
  width: 50px;
  top: 75vh;
  right: 45%;
  border-radius: 0 50px 50px 0;
}

.carousel-control-prev {
  top: 75vh;;
  width: 50px;
  left: 49%;
  border-radius: 50px 0 0 50px;
}

.carousel-control-prev-icon,
.carousel-control-next-icon {
  height: 60px;
  width: 50px;
  bottom: 10px;
  background-size: 100%, 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.carousel-control-next-icon:after
{
  content: '>';
  font-size: 35px;
}

.carousel-control-prev-icon:after {
  content: '<';
  font-size: 35px;
  color: gray;
}
```

Thanks ahead of time for any assistance!

Comment: share a snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few options here. I'd suggest using flexbox if possible. Its best to control top from the .button class. You dont need absolute positioning on either carousel-control-next or carousel-control-prev classes. dont forget to close the buttons div too

```
.buttons{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center
}

.carousel-control-next {
  width: 50px;
  top: 75vh; //control top from .buttons not here
  right: 45%; // this is not needed. to override. set right: inherit
  border-radius: 0 50px 50px 0;
}

.carousel-control-prev {
  width: 50px;
  top: 75vh; //control top from .buttons not here
  right: 45%; // this is not needed. to override. set right: inherit
  border-radius: 0 50px 50px 0;
}
```